# WKWebView Won't Load (NSViewController, OS X)

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, wkwebview

I am trying to build a simple WKWebView application that will display Google in the WebView. The app works perfectly fine; however, upon implementing the WKWebView, the app no longer shows a window. It just simply launches the app (in the dock) with no NSView in sight.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!

        let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

There doesn't seem to be any further examples online, nor does there seem to be any projects on GitHub.

Thanks. I haven't come across this before.

Comment: Define a `frame` for your `WKWebView` and add it to `self.view` using `addSubview` instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 43):

I guess there're some limitations behind Xcode Settings those hidden settings make your WKWebView NOT WORK!!!

You could try these ways, Maybe you will find the solution:

1) Search these key words by Google, You'll find some tutorials:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

2) Check your Project Setting panel. Make sure you've CHECKED the NetWork [Incoming] & [OutComing] item:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: One thing I noticed, it appears you only need the second part (Incoming and outcoming in App Sandbox) after you have started using automatic provisioning and tied the app to iTunes.  Before doing that, it seems to work without those sandbox settings.

Comment: Thanks!
Doing this, it works. But only running thought Xcode. If I run by opening the "app" generated it doesn't load anything, and not giving errors.

Comment: I only needed the `Outgoing Connections (Client)` portion to get `WKWebView` to work.  I left the other unchecked because I don't plan on my app being a server.  There's more documentation on it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html).

Comment: Just spent about 15 minutes pulling my hear out at this to realise I just needed to check the incoming and outgoing connections in the sandbox config....
This should really be highlighted in the console, similar to not having the correct privacy string fields set for features such as location services or camera usage.

Comment: Perfect, thanks... setting that client is always a stumbling block!

Comment: Please everybody upvote this answer, just saved me from going insane after trying to get WKWebView to work for half a day.

Comment: Thank you! Needed to tick the boxes only

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 14 I needed the 'outgoing connection' and additionally the frame:

```
var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    // these two lines are important:
    super.loadView()
    webView = WKWebView(frame:self.view.frame)

    view = webView
    
    let url = URL(string:"https://www.example.com/")!
    let req = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(req)
    
    // webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body bgcolor=red><p>Hello, World!</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
}
```