# Using WKWebView in my current project results in a blank screen

Tags: swift, macos, webkit, wkwebview

I have seen many many q/a on this topic including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462981/wkwebview-wont-load-nsviewcontroller-os-x), [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125271) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291678/wkwebview-not-loading-webpage-renders-blank-screen-in-swift). I believe I have tried every answer given. This is annoying, as I'm using my technique in four other apps and they are working fine. I even copied the code and storyboard from one project that does work to this one, but still no joy.

My code is this:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit


    class HelpViewController: NSViewController {

         @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()

            let url = URL(string:"https://www.apple.com")!
            webView.load(URLRequest (url: url))

          }

    }
```

I have my info.plist without NSAppTransportSecurity

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

although I've tried it as well with this code included.

Under ProjectName > Signing and Capabilities, I have this:

[image]

I must be missing something, but I'm asking here in case someone else has also experienced this.
I'm using Xcode 11.4 (and I've tried 11.5 b1).

Thanks in advance for any places I can look.

Comment: Tried your code with Xcode 11.4.1 and it worked for me! Did you verify the size of the webview at runtime?

Comment: Not sure I know the  appropriate way to size the webView . Is this what you mean: webView.fittingSize in which case it's (0.0, 0.0). hmm

Comment: You’d size it like any view. For instance in your storyboard, you can use autolayout to set size and position constraints between the webview and its parent. You can also do it by code obviously.

Comment: Yes, it's sized in the storyboard. Should have said.

Comment: Also, I copied the code from one project to another, and in the second, the code worked just fine. I'll get there.

Comment: Did you properly set the view controller’s name to “ HelpViewController” in the storyboard?

Comment: yep. that all looks good. I'm thinking there is something in the signing of the app that's askew.

Comment: Maybe you can use the debug view hierarchy to confirm the webview is not sized (0, 0), and monitor the web request using WKWebView's navigationDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem, I resolved it by turning off the AppSandbox in the info.plist file.

Run the app again, the link worked.

Turn the AppSandbox on again.
Turn on the outgoing connections.

The problem was solved for me.